# How to fill pandas column (variable) using two conditions at once

Tags: python, pandas

The following code works fine, but I failed to make it a single-liner. Is it possible?

```
dat.loc[dat['A'] == '', 'A'] = 'no'
dat.loc[dat['A'].isnull(), 'A'] = 'no'
```

(It is strange, though, that after merging two dataframes A contains both empty strings and nulls. )

Answer (score 0):

A one liner could be:

```
dat.loc[dat['A'].fillna('') == '', 'A'] = 'no'
```

Or:

```
dat.loc[dat['A'].eq('')|dat['A'].isnull(), 'A'] = 'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dat['A'] = dat['A'].fillna('no').replace('', 'no')
```